# What are the campaign settings published for AD&D 2nd Ed?

Tags: adnd-2e, campaign-settings

I've been playing Dungeons & Dragons since the second edition, and my brother and I want to try to buy used second edition campaign box settings (Forgotten Realms, Dragonlance, etc...).

When I search (mostly on eBay), I find several campaign boxes of some of the campaign settings, all with different components inside.

For example, I know that for Greyhawk setting there is one book with a knight on the cover and another one with a flying griffin. I suppose they are different editions, but I am not sure.

Can someone explain to me what are the main campaigns of Advanced Dungeons & Dragons 2nd Edition? Ideally with visuals or references for identifying them visually?

A reliable reference where I can see actual photos of the products, with the components inside, would be great.

Comment: I gave this an overhaul. Could you look it over and make sure it’s accurate to what you want to ask, and make any changes it needs? If it looks good, we can lift the hold and let the answering begin.